# In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$, how do I see if there are no elements of a certain norm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, normed-spaces

The ring is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$, where $D$ is a square free integer.
Define the norm $N: \mathbb Z[\sqrt D] \rightarrow \mathbb N$, $N(a+b\sqrt D)= |a^2-Db^2|$.

To show that there is no element of a certain norm, my Abstract Algebra book uses clever tricks involving modulo.

It takes some effort to show it, but in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 10]$, there are no elements of norm 2 or norm 5. At first I thought that this was because $10=2*5$. But the next example showed me that this guess was probably wrong: In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt -5]$, there are no elements of norm 3.

Can we generalize a statements about these rings $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$? That is, I want to know if there is a better method than guessing and checking just by looking at the integer $D$.

Comment: This is, in general, not an easy problem. There is some discussion in Chrystal's Algebra. Also, the usual definition of norm does not have that absolute value sign in it. A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $a^2-Db^2=m$ to have a solution is for $m$ to be a quadratic residue modulo $D$.

Comment: The general case is not easy. See the book [Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/primes.html), by Cox.

Comment: When $D$ is negative, this reduces to a finite brute force check. When $D$ is positive, you're dealing with a generalized Pell equation.

Comment: It doesn’t take any effort to see that $2$ is not of the form $m^2-10n^2$, since, reading this norm form modulo $10$ gives you simply $m^2$. But the only squares modulo $10$ are $0,\pm1,\pm4$ and $5$. Since neither $2$ nor $8$ appears on this list, you’re done.

Comment: @Lubin please, edit your comment to include $3$.

Comment: Is there a square that is 3 mod 10?

Comment: sorry,  @Kumar, comments are not editable beyond 5 minutes. Just check the OP’s comment above.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
$D$ is a squarefree integer if one of the following holds:
(i) $D$ is a prime number $p$ or a finite product of *distinct* prime numbers.
(ii) $D$ is $-p$ or negative of finite product of *distinct* prime numbers.

**My Assumption:** $D$ belongs to (i)

Now, Let $a^2-Db^2=m$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.
 Now taking $mod$ $D$ on both sides we get
 $a^2\equiv m$ $mod$ $D$
$\iff m\equiv a^2$ $mod$ $D$

Now, Use *Chinese Remainder Theorem for simultaneous linear congruences* to get the solutions for $m$.

**Remarks:**
We will always get a square integer as the norm( it may not be possibly indicated by the solutions of Chinese remainder theorem for simultaneous congruences)

Comment: @Brahadeesh can you please help to revise my solution?

Comment: Okay, Sorry, I am wrong with the example, but the Chinese Remainder Theorem shows that it is a solution.

Comment: There must be an error in your application of CRT, @Kumar.